# how to make typescript class to have properties loaded from json and to have intellisense for this properties

Tags: json, typescript

I would like to load json from file and then make some class to have properties from this json. Loading json can be achieved with this:

```
import * as loadedJson from "./jsonFile.json";
```

and then I can even create a type:

```
export type loadedJsonType  = typeof loadedJson;
```

And using this **loadedJsonType** the intellisense shows properties from the json, as expected.

But how to make some class to have properties of this **loadedJsonType** and to have intellisense? I can implement this type on a class:

```
export class SomeClass extends BaseClass implements loadedJsonType {}
```

but still have to implement all properties of the json to remove compiler errors. I do not want to rewrite all properties. Object.assign also does not seem to help much because does not give intellisense.

Comment: I don't get it. Do you only want to implement *some* parts of the JSON?

Comment: I want to implement all the JSON. All the properties JSON has. But I do not want to implement them again, but to automatically infer from JSON.